# Is there any way to find when the user joined a discord server? My bot returns undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}whois`)){
        var Member = message.mentions.users.first()
        if(!Member){
            var Member = message.author
        }
        var status = Member.presence.status
        if(status == "dnd"){
            var status = "Do not Disturb"
        }
        let whoisEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Who is ${Member.username}?`)
            .setColor("PURPLE")
            .setDescription(`ID: ${Member.id}`)
            .setThumbnail(Member.displayAvatarURL())
            .addField("Joined at", Member.joinedAt)
            .addField("Status", status)
            .addField("Created at", Member.createdAt)
            .setFooter(d)
        message.channel.send(whoisEmbed)
    }
```

Everything works except Member.joinedAt. The bot says:

Joined At
Undefined

When I run the code

Answer (score 0):

You can just change `message.mentions.users.first()` to `message.mentions.members.first()` and `var Member = message.author` to `var Member = message.member`

Answer (score 0):

The reason `User.joinedAt` is returning undefined is because `joinedAt` is a property of a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), not a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). A `GuildMember` is tied to a specific guild, which is how Discord can find when they joined. However, if you invoked this method on a `User`, Discord wouldn't know which guild to look at.

You can fix this by replacing:

```js
message.mentions.users.first(); // returns a user

// with:

message.mentions.members.first(); // returns a member
```

And replacing:

```js
message.author; // returns a user

// with:

message.member; // returns a member
```